# Laravel Blade PHP component class get parent data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, balde

I am creating some Laravel blade components.

I have several components with PHP class with corresponding view files.

I need parent component data in my PHP Class.

I know that it is possible in view file using @aware(['color' => 'gray'])

But Is it possible to get data in the PHP component? Then How?

For example, I have two components

```
Components/Menu.php 
Componets/MenuItem.php
```

I need some `Components/Menu.php`  data inside `Componets/MenuItem.php`

Comment: try  `@include` and  `@yield` to achieve this. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade

Comment: Can you add some code to explain the data you need to get from the parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inheritance :
The child class will inherit all the public and protected properties and methods from the parent class.

**Menu Component:**

```
namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Menu extends Component
{
    public $parent_Data;

    public function __construct($parent_Data)
    {
        $this->parent_Data = $parent_Data;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('Menu');
    }
}
```

**MenuItem Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component\Menu;

class MenuItem extends Menu
{
    public $publicData;

    public function __construct($publicData,$parent_Data)
    {
        $this->parent_Data = $parent_Data;
        $this->publicData = $publicData;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('MenuItem');
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the command to make MenuItem inherit from Menu Or i will  create this classes manually